# Angular 2 dynamic strings with pipes

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to set a dynamic page title and use a pipe but I can't seem to get the string to render and use the pipe at the same time.

Title without the pipe is `<ion-title> Add {{pageTitle}} transaction </ion-title>` which becomes "Add payment transaction" or "Add income transaction". Once the title is rendered I want to be able to use my language translation pipe called `translate` like `Add {{pageTitle}} transaction | translate`.

I tried:

```
{{ Add {{pageTitle}} transaction | translate }}

{{ Add ${pageTitle} transaction | translate }}

{{ `"Add ${pageTitle} transaction"` | translate }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ 'Add ' + pageTitle + ' transaction' | translate }}
```